# Magento 2 added custom column in sales order grid but unable to filterable

Tags: magento2

I have added a product name column in the sale order grid from XML and it shows correctly on the grid but if I use it in filter form it gives the error as "Something went wrong" and the error log has below error

```
main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE  (((`products` LIKE '%nato%')))
```

added below code in sales_order_grid file in custom module

```
<column name="products" class="Custom\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductName">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Items Name</item>
                <item name="disableAction" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Then created UI component column at Custom\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns

```
class ProductName extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                
                $productArr = [];
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($items["entity_id"]);

                foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $productArr[] = $item->getName(); //to get product name
                }
                $items['products'] = implode(" , " , $productArr);
                unset($productArr);
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Filter will not work with this method.

Use below code for reference -

1. sales_order_grid.xml

   ```
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_columns">
            <column name="column_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Colum Test</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
   ```
2. Create di.xml in adminhtml of module

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <!-- Plugins -->
        <!-- Adds additional data to the orders grid collection -->
        <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
            <plugin name="mageworx_extended_orders_grid_add_data_to_orders_grid"
                    type="Vendor\Name\Plugin\AddDataToOrdersGrid"
                    sortOrder="10"
                    disabled="false"/>
        </type>
         <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
            <plugin name="sales_grid_collection" type="Vendor\Name\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order\Grid"/>
        </type>
    </config>
   ```
3. AddDataToOrdersGrid.php

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Vendor\Name\Plugin;
> class AddDataToOrdersGrid
> {
>    
>     private $logger;
>
>     public function __construct(
>         \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $customLogger,
>         array $data = []
>     ) {
>         $this->logger   = $customLogger;
>     }
>     public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
>     {
>         if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
>             return $collection;
>         }
>
>         if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
>             try {
>               
>             
>                 $collection->getSelect()
>                 ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
>                 ->columns(array('main_table.*','main_table.products AS test_product')); 
>             } catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
>                 $this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
>             }
>         }
>         return $collection;
>     }
> }
> ```

4. Grid.php

   getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {$where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
    foreach($where as $key => $w){
    if (str_contains($w, 'test_product')) { 
    $where[$key] = str_replace("`test_product`","main_table.products",$w);
                                }
                            } 
    $collection->getSelect->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where);            
                        }
                        return $collection;
                    }
                }

Hope It helps!!

You need to maybe modify the code a bit the get your desired result.